# Floating element destroys layout

Tags: html, css

I have a magnific popup. If I want to float an element so that two elements appear next to each other, the layout of the popup gets destroyed.

See yourself by putting the image and text next to each other with "float: left":

http://jsfiddle.net/a7Vj8/1/

When I want to float image and text, the white background becomes smaller. Where is the problem? It always happens when I use "float:left".

Here comes my HTML:

```
<div id="modal_profile_organisor" class="white_modal mfp-hide">

                    <div class="modal_padding">

                            <h3>Organisor</h3>

                            <div class="modal_organisor_details">

                                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
                                <p>Some small text</p>



                            </div>


                    </div> <!-- /.modal_padding -->

                </div> <!-- /#modal_profile_organisor -->

<a href="#modal_profile_organisor" id="popup_organisor_modal">open modal</a>
```

Comment: Can you actually include the error in the jsfiddle? It's not clear where you add the `float: left` that generates the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `floats` you have to `clear` these floats at the position where you no longer need elements to float, e.g. with a `clear: both;`

A working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7Vj8/11/)**

Here is a `clearfix` class that [HTML5 BOILERPLATE](http://html5boilerplate.com/) uses:

```
/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

With this you can set the `clearfix` class to the wrapping container of the floating elements.

Answer (score 1):

When all the contents of the `.modal_organisor_details` div are floated, there's nothing to give the container any size. Adding `overflow: auto` to the container creates a new float context, and solves that:

```
.modal_organisor_details {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal_organisor_details img, .modal_organisor_details p
{
  float: left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a7Vj8/2/